# Javascript chained destructuring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

```
const someFunction = ({ a }) => {
  const { b } = a;
  return <div>{b}</div>
}

const obj = { a: { b: 1 } }
someFunction(obj)
```

Is there a way to chain object destructuring so that in `someFunction`, we can destructure `obj` to get `b` within the parameter instead of having to do a separate `const { b } = a` in the function body?

Comment: Sure try `{ a: { b } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like so:

```js
const someFunction = ({ a: { b } }) => {
  return b;
}

const obj = { a: { b: 1 } };
console.log(someFunction(obj));
```